# Manipulate a 2D point controlled simultaneously by Locator and its coordinates

Tags: graphics, manipulate, locator

I'm trying to have a point in the plane which can be manipulated both using `Locator` as well as inserting its $x$ and $y$ coordinates. My attempts at doing this are:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Point[p], PlotRange -> 1], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator},  
 {p[[1]], -1, 1}, {p[[2]], -1, 1}]
```

which doesn't even run, as well as

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Point[p], PlotRange -> 1], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}, 
 {p[1], -1, 1}, {p[2], -1, 1}]
```

which runs, but fails to see that `p[1]`, `p[2]` should be the coordinates of `p`.

I've managed to use a `2DSlider`:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Point[p], PlotRange -> 1], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}, 
 {p, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]
```

but even here, I can't input the exact coordinates.

My question is:

How can one give the exact coordinates of the point `p` in `Manipulate`, as well as control its position using a `Locator`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can add the option `Appearance -> "Labeled"` to a `Slider2D` to have the current values shown as an **editable** label.

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[p]}, 
  PlotRange -> 1], {{p, {1, 1}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: GIF]

---

Using two 1D `Slider`

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[{px, py}]}, 
  PlotRange -> 1], {{px, 1}, -1, 1, Slider, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{py, 1}, -1, 1, VerticalSlider, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled", ControlPlacement -> Left}]
```

[image: GIF2]

---

Having several interconnected control types:

```
point = Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}]}, PlotRange -> 1];

Manipulate[
 Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> 1, Frame -> True], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> point, TrackingFunction -> (p = #; {px, py} = p; &)},
 {{p, {1, 1}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  TrackingFunction -> (p = #; {px, py} = p; &)},
 {{px, 1}, -1, 1, Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  TrackingFunction -> (px = #; p[[1]] = px; &)},
 {{py, 1}, -1, 1, VerticalSlider, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ControlPlacement -> Left, 
  TrackingFunction -> (py = #; p[[2]] = py; &)},
 {{px, 1}, InputField, ControlPlacement -> Bottom, 
  TrackingFunction -> (px = #; p[[1]] = px; &)},
 {{py, 1}, InputField, ControlPlacement -> Bottom, 
  TrackingFunction -> (py = #; p[[2]] = py; &)}]
```

[image: UltimateMess]

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer controlling the coordinates separately.

Comment: I'm having difficulties doing that. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think you can move the point using locator as well.

Comment: @user1337 I added a version with several different interconnected controllers. You can keep the ones you want and remove the others from the code.

Answer (score 1):

What about the InputField:

```
    Manipulate[
 Graphics[Point[p], PlotRange -> 1], {{p, {1, 1}}, 
  Locator}, {p, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, InputField}]
```

??

Comment: I'd like to have two input fields for the two coordinates.