# Multiple interactive adjusters for multiple parameters including locator

Tags: plotting, manipulate, dynamic, interactive

I want to make a program that allows to vary multiple parameters via multiple adjusters. It may well be that this question has been answered already somewhere. However, I am pretty new to programming in *Mathematica* and many times the answers to questions here are just completely overwhelming my rudimentary skills.

As said, I would like different adjusters, namely: A slider, an input field and grabbing objects in a plot environment. In addition I want to constrain the grabbing bit to be only in a horizontal motion. Basically I want to extend the Psst!-program from the University of St. Andrews.

I can do just the grabbing bit with

```
LocatorPane[{Dynamic[pt]}, Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}], {{0, 0}, {10, 0}}, 
 Appearance -> Graphics[Line[{{0, 1}, {0, -1}}]]]
```

Where I have restricted the `LocatorPane` to a line and substituted the adjuster appearance with a line (later this could be the image of say a lens in an optical system).

If I just wanted to have the `Slider` and `InputField`, I would just use the `Manipulate` environment and overlay with a line:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Epilog -> {Line[{{0, -1}, {0, 1}}], Line[{{2 Pi, -1}, {2 Pi, 1}}], 
   Line[{{p, -1}, {p, 1}}]}], {p, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Here there is no grabbing. I can combine the two (somewhat) with `DynamicModule`:

```
DynamicModule[{pt}, {Slider[Dynamic[pt], {0, 10}],  
  InputField[Dynamic[pt]], 
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}], {{0, 0}, {10, 0}}, 
   Appearance -> {Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, 1}, {0, -1}}]}], 
  Graphics[{Black, Line[{{0, 1}, {0, -1}}]}]}]}]
```

The first issue pops up here. Everything is well behaved when I use the slider, i.e. the input field displays a single number and the line moves to the correct spot. However, once I grab the line and move it, the input field displays a vector and the sliders resets to 0.

I want to extend this to 2 or more parameters (and lines), so I went with

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {{1, 0}, {6, 0}}}, {LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],   
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}], {{0, 0}, {10, 0}},
  Appearance -> {Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, 1}, {0, -1}}]}],
  Graphics[{Black, Line[{{0, 1}, {0, -1}}]}]}]}]
```

Which works fine. However, in addition to the above problems with the slider and input field when those are added, the second line will vanish once the slider is touched.

I have played around using `Dynamic[First[pt]]` for the vector problem to no avail. I see how it would be difficult to determine which parameter I want to vary when I define only a single dynamic variable like this,

```
{pt = {{1, 0}, {6, 0}}}
```

so I went for the more intuitive version of

```
DynamicModule[{pt1 = {1, 0}, pt2 = {6, 0}}, 
 {Slider[Dynamic[pt1], {0, 10}], InputField[Dynamic[pt1]], 
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[{pt1, pt2}], Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}], {{0, 0}, {10, 0}},
   Appearance -> {Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, 1}, {0, -1}}]}], 
  Graphics[{Black, Line[{{0, 1}, {0, -1}}]}]}]}]
```

But this does not change anything at all.

I would be greatful if people could explain where things went wrong.

---

Based on the answers by @Algohi and @Karsten 7. I have produced the two following working examples based on Karsten's answer

```
line[a_] := Graphics[{a, Line[{{0, 1}, {0, -1}}]}]
DynamicModule[{p = {1, 0}, px = 1, q = {2, 0}, qx = 2, r = {3, 0}, rx = 3},
Column[{
Row[{"a", Slider[Dynamic[px, (px = #; p[[1]] = px; &)], {0, 10},Appearance -> "Labeled"],
InputField[Dynamic[px, (px = #; p[[1]] = px; &)]]}],
Row[{"b", Slider[Dynamic[qx, (qx = #; q[[1]] = qx; &)], {0, 10}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"],
InputField[Dynamic[qx, (qx = #; q[[1]] = qx; &)]]}],
Row[{"c", Slider[Dynamic[rx, (rx = #; r[[1]] = rx; &)], {0, 10},Appearance -> "Labeled"],
InputField[Dynamic[rx, (rx = #; r[[1]] = rx; &)]]}],
Row[{LocatorPane[Dynamic[{p, q, r}, (
p = {First@#[[1]], 0}; px = First@p;
q = {First@#[[2]], 0}; qx = First@q;
r = {First@#[[3]], 0}; rx = First@r; &)]
, Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 300], {{0, 0}, {10, 0}}, Appearance -> {line[Black], line[Blue], line[Red]}]
, {"a=" Dynamic@p[[1]], "b=" Dynamic@q[[1]], "c=" Dynamic@r[[1]]}}]}]]
```

and

```
DynamicModule[{pt1 = {1, 0}, pt2 = {6, 0}, pt3 = {3, 0}},
Column[{
Row[{"a", Slider[Dynamic[pt1[[1]]], {0, 10}],InputField[Dynamic[pt1[[1]]]]}],
Row[{"b", Slider[Dynamic[pt2[[1]]], {0, 10}],InputField[Dynamic[pt2[[1]]]]}],
Row[{"c", Slider[Dynamic[pt3[[1]]], {0, 10}],InputField[Dynamic[pt3[[1]]]]}], 
Row[{LocatorPane[Dynamic[{pt1, pt2, pt3}], 
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 300], {{0, 0}, {10, 0}}, Appearance -> {line[Black], line[Blue], line[Red]}],
{"a=" Dynamic@pt1[[1]], "b=" Dynamic@pt2[[1]], "c=" Dynamic@pt3[[1]]}}]}]]
```

based on Algohi's answer.

Comment: Probably the easy way to fix your code without much work is to change Input field into `InputField[Dynamic[If[Length[pt] > 1, pt[[1]], pt]]]`

Comment: Thanks, that does fix the issue if you use a single parameter quite easily. However, the second one still vanishes.

Comment: @Christain, when you touch the slider the point pt1 changes from vector {a,b} into scalar a. This means the `LocatorPane` will have only one point which means one locator. A simple fix to this can be by using `Slider[Dynamic[pt1[[1]]], {0, 10}]`

Comment: @Algohi Hum, I thought `First[pt]` would be identical to `pt[[1]]`, but while the former (which I tried) returns: `Set::write: "Tag First in First[{6,0}] is Protected."` the second does exactly what I thought it should. Very strange.

Sadly, it seems I cannot upvote your contribution which fixes my problem.

Comment: Actually, I just noted that with the `InputField[Dynamic[If[Length[pt] > 1, pt[[1]], pt]]]` when I try using the input field, it says `Set::write: "Tag If in If[False,FE`pt1$$21[[1]],FE`pt1$$21] is Protected."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using `TrackingFunction` or the second argument of `Dynamic`

An adaption of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87698/18476) to your problem:

```
line = Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, 1}, {0, -1}}]}, PlotRange -> 1];

Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}], 
 {{p, {1, 1}}, {0, 0}, {10, 0}, Locator, Appearance -> line, 
  TrackingFunction -> (p = {First@#, 0}; px = First@p; &)}, 
 {{px, 1}, 0, 10, Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  TrackingFunction -> (px = #; p[[1]] = px; &)}, 
 {{px, 1}, InputField, ControlPlacement -> Bottom, 
  TrackingFunction -> (px = #; p[[1]] = px; &)}]
```

[image: ManipulateOut]

Using `DynamicModule` and `LocatorPane`:

```
DynamicModule[{p = {1, 0}, px = 1}, 
 Panel@Grid[{
  {Slider[Dynamic[px, (px = #; p[[1]] = px; &)], {0, 10}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]}, 
  {InputField[Dynamic[px, (px = #; p[[1]] = px; &)]]},
  {LocatorPane[Dynamic[p, (p = {First@#, 0}; px = First@p; &)], 
    Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 300], {{0, 0}, {10, 0}}, 
    Appearance -> {Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, 1}, {0, -1}}]}]}],
   Dynamic@p}}]]
```

[image: DynamicModuleOut]

**Short explanation:**
`p` is the point of the `Locator`. Whenever the `Locator` is changed `p` gets set to `p = {First@#, 0}&`. This pure function is applied to the position of the `Locator`, whenever it gets moved and therefore restricts its movement to a horizontal movement. `px` is the horizontal position of the `Locator`. Whenever it is changed the x-coordinate of `p` (`p[[1]]`) gets updated by `p[[1]] = px`. The value of `px` gets updated to `px = First@p`, whenever the `Locator` is moved.

### Using `Dynamic[p[[1]]]` instead of `Dynamic[First[pt]]`

A little simpler `DynamicModule` (as also suggested in a [comment by Algohi](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96161/multiple-interactive-adjusters-for-multiple-parameters-including-locator/96163#comment260313_96161), mainly using `Dynamic[p[[1]]]` instead of the not working `Dynamic[First[pt]]` you tried):

```
DynamicModule[{p = {1, 0}}, 
 Panel@Grid[{
  {Slider[Dynamic[p[[1]]], {0, 10}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]}, 
  {InputField[Dynamic[p[[1]]]]}, 
  {LocatorPane[Dynamic[p], 
    Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 300], {{0, 0}, {10, 0}}, 
    Appearance -> {Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, 1}, {0, -1}}]}]}], 
   Dynamic@p}}]]
```

**Why does using `Dynamic[p[[1]]]`, but not `Dynamic[First[pt]]`?**
When `Dynamic[p[[1]]]` is used, the first part of `p` gets `Set` dynamically. Whereas `Dynamic[First[pt]]` tries to dynamically change the `DownValues` of `First`. This is not allowed, as `First` has the `Attributes` `{Protected}`.
[image: illustrativeExample]

Comment: Hey Karsten, that certainly works. However, since I don't understand what's going on, I sadly cannot extend this to multiple parameters (or learn from it). Could you possibly explain what's done there?

Also, the locators are not restricted in their vertical motion.

Comment: @Christian The `Locator`s should be restricted to horizontal motion only now.

Comment: Check the [`Dynamic` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html?q=Dynamic) (including the *Details and Options* sections), especially regarding the second argument of `Dynamic`, for detailed explanations of what is going on. `TrackingFunction` is the same as the second argument to `Dynamic`, but within a `Manipulate`.

Comment: I understand your answer now and have been able to extend to 3 parameters without problems. Thanks for your effort!