# ClickPane and InputField entry in a Manipulate

Tags: function-construction, manipulate, inputfield

By clicking at a point on the slope field for an ode, a solution is plotted through that point. Additional clicks produce more plots; the plots are saved in `graph` and the points in `pt`. The following code is a slimmed down version.

```
Manipulate[
 ClickPane[
  Show[
   Plot[graph, {t, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}],
   sf@dx[ode],
   Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[pt]}]],

  (AppendTo[graph, sol[dx[ode], #]];
   AppendTo[pt, #]) &],

 Style["Enter f(t,x)"], {{ode, x^2 - t, "dx/dt = "}},

 (*
 TrackingFunction\[Rule](pt=#;{t0,x0}=pt;&);
 {{t0,0},InputField,TrackingFunction\[Rule](t0=#;pt[[1]]=t0;&)},
 {{x0,0},InputField,TrackingFunction\[Rule](x0=#;pt[[2]]=x0;&)},
 *)

 Button["Delete all solutions", graph = {}; pt = {}, 
 ImageSize -> {Automatic, 20}],

 Initialization :> (
   graph = {}; pt = {};

   dx[de_] := ode;
   sf[ode_] := 
    VectorPlot[{1, ode}, {t, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}, VectorPoints -> 17, 
    VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, None}, 
    VectorStyle -> {{Red, Arrowheads[0]}}, ImagePadding -> 1, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"];

   sol[dx_, {t0_, x0_}] := 
   y[t] /. First@
   NDSolve[{y'[t] == dx /. {x -> y[t]}, y[t0] == x0, 
   WhenEvent[Abs[y[t]] > 2.5 , "StopIntegration"]}, y, {t, -2, 2},
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
     "WarningMessage" -> False}];)
 ]
```

I want to accomplish the same by `InputField` of the initial point as well. All these plots are to be appended in `graph` and the the inputted initial point `{t0,x0}` appended to `pt`. In particular, `graph` and `pt` may contain plots and initial points from either `ClickPane` entries or `InputField` entries. I thought that `TrackingFunction` (see [Karsten 7](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87689/manipulate-a-2d-point-controlled-simultaneously-by-locator-and-its-coordinates/87698#87698)) might make this possible; if it does, I haven't coded it properly. (See the commented lines in the code.) Is this possible or is there another way? I realize that my implementation of the commented code is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix of your code:

```
Manipulate[
 ClickPane[
  Show[Plot[graph, {t, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}], sf@dx[ode], 
   Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[pt]}]], 
  (AppendTo[graph, sol[dx[ode], #]]; AppendTo[pt, #]; t0x0 = #) &], 
 Style["Enter f(t,x)"], {{ode, x^2 - t, "dx/dt = "}}, 
 {{t0x0, {0, 0}, "{t0, x0}"}, InputField, 
  TrackingFunction -> (t0x0 = #; AppendTo[graph, sol[dx[ode], #]]; AppendTo[pt, #]; &)}, 
 Button["Delete all solutions", graph = {}; pt = {}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 20}], 
 Initialization :> (graph = {}; pt = {};
   dx[de_] := ode;
   sf[ode_] := 
    VectorPlot[{1, ode}, {t, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}, VectorPoints -> 17, 
     VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, None}, 
     VectorStyle -> {{Red, Arrowheads[0]}}, ImagePadding -> 1, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"];
   sol[dx_, {t0_, x0_}] := 
    y[t] /. First@
      NDSolve[{y'[t] == dx /. {x -> y[t]}, y[t0] == x0, 
        WhenEvent[Abs[y[t]] > 2.5, "StopIntegration"]}, y, {t, -2, 2},
        "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
         "WarningMessage" -> False}];)]
```

---

Update based on the [comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100471/clickpane-and-inputfield-entry-in-a-manipulate/100475?noredirect=1#comment272735_100475):

```
Manipulate[
 ClickPane[
  Show[Plot[graph, {t, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}], 
   sf@dx[ode], 
   Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[pt]}]], (AppendTo[graph, 
     sol[dx[ode], #]]; AppendTo[pt, #]; t0x0 = #; {t0, x0} = #) &],
 Style["Enter f(t,x)"],
 {{ode, x^2 - t, "dx/dt = "}, InputField},
 {{t0, 0}, InputField, 
  TrackingFunction -> (t0 = #; AppendTo[graph, sol[dx[ode], {#, x0}]];
     AppendTo[pt, {#, x0}]; t0x0 = {#, x0}; &)},
 {{x0, 0}, InputField, 
  TrackingFunction -> (x0 = #; AppendTo[graph, sol[dx[ode], {t0, #}]];
     AppendTo[pt, {t0, #}]; t0x0 = {t0, #}; &)},
 {{t0x0, {0, 0}, "{t0, x0}"}, InputField, 
  TrackingFunction -> (t0x0 = #; AppendTo[graph, sol[dx[ode], #]];
     AppendTo[pt, #]; {t0, x0} = #; &)}, 
 Button["Delete all solutions", graph = {}; pt = {}, 
  ImageSize -> {Automatic, 20}], 
 Initialization :> (graph = {}; pt = {};
   dx[de_] := ode;
   sf[ode_] := 
    VectorPlot[{1, ode}, {t, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}, VectorPoints -> 17, 
     VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, None}, 
     VectorStyle -> {{Red, Arrowheads[0]}}, ImagePadding -> 1, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"];
   sol[dx_, {t0_, x0_}] := 
    y[t] /. First@
      NDSolve[{y'[t] == dx /. {x -> y[t]}, y[t0] == x0, 
        WhenEvent[Abs[y[t]] > 2.5, "StopIntegration"]}, y, {t, -2, 2},
        "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
         "WarningMessage" -> False}];)]
```

Or

```
Manipulate[
 ClickPane[
  Show[Plot[graph, {t, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}], 
   sf@dx[ode], 
   Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[pt]}]], (AppendTo[graph, 
     sol[dx[ode], #]]; AppendTo[pt, #]; {t0, x0} = #) &],
 Style["Enter f(t,x)"],
 {{ode, x^2 - t, "dx/dt = "}, InputField},
 {{t0, 0}, InputField, 
  TrackingFunction -> (t0 = #; AppendTo[graph, sol[dx[ode], {#, x0}]];
     AppendTo[pt, {#, x0}]; &)},
 {{x0, 0}, InputField, 
  TrackingFunction -> (x0 = #; AppendTo[graph, sol[dx[ode], {t0, #}]];
     AppendTo[pt, {t0, #}]; &)}, 
 Button["Delete all solutions", graph = {}; pt = {}, 
  ImageSize -> {Automatic, 20}], 
 Initialization :> (graph = {}; pt = {};
   dx[de_] := ode;
   sf[ode_] := 
    VectorPlot[{1, ode}, {t, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}, VectorPoints -> 17, 
     VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, None}, 
     VectorStyle -> {{Red, Arrowheads[0]}}, ImagePadding -> 1, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"];
   sol[dx_, {t0_, x0_}] := 
    y[t] /. 
     First@NDSolve[{y'[t] == dx /. {x -> y[t]}, y[t0] == x0, 
        WhenEvent[Abs[y[t]] > 2.5, "StopIntegration"]}, y, {t, -2, 2},
        "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
         "WarningMessage" -> False}];)]
```

Comment: 7; Thank you for the fix - so elegant! I have tried to modify your code to provide separate InputFields for t0 and x0 but have not been successful. In fact, I really don't understand how TrackingFunction works. Can you help me?

Comment: @Stephen Did you check the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackingFunction.html) (including the **Details** section)? `TrackingFunction` works like the second argument of [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html?q=Dynamic).

Comment: 7: A new pt with the new t0

Comment: 7: If only t0 is changed, then x0 remains the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32162/discussion-between-stephen-and-karsten-7).