# Using Interval Slider in Manipulate for Plot Functionality

Tags: plotting, manipulate, dynamic, slider

I am trying to incorporate Interval Sliders in `Manipulate` to allow the user to select a range to view a given plot.  Here is an example that I have constructed for the sake of the question.

```
opt := {PlotStyle -> Orange, AxesLabel -> {"\[Mu]s", "V"}, 
  ImageSize -> 300}
Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[10/x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-1, V}}, 
  Evaluate[opt]], {{V, 0}, -1, 1}, ControlType -> VerticalSlider, 
  ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

I want to create a vertical Interval Slider to allow the user to control the view of the plot. By having the user choose the appropriate positions of the sliders, the plot should return the `Plot` with `PlotRange -> {{0,5},{Vmin, Vmax}}`. Similarly, I also want to create a second horizontal slider in the same panel underneath the displayed plot to mimic the same thing for the x-axis. Does `Manipulate` support multiple sliders in one function?

Also, very minor follow-up questions: How can I display the values of the Interval Slider and furthermore let the user input some values defining the interval so that the plot displays the range specified by the user?

Thank you so much. I have been fiddling around with `ControlType->IntervalSlider` but couldn't figure out a way to have `Manipulate` interpret the parameters that I have set.

Comment: you may be interested in: [How to manipulate 2D plots?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7142/5478)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should give you a starting point:

```
opt = {PlotStyle -> Orange, AxesLabel -> {"\[Mu]s", "V"}, ImageSize -> 300}

Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[10/x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {xInt, {vMin, vMax}}, Evaluate[opt]], 
  {{vMax, 0}, -1, 1, VerticalSlider, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{vMin, -1}, -1, 1, VerticalSlider, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{xInt, {0, 5}, Row[{Spacer[40], "x interval"}]}, 0, 5, ControlType -> IntervalSlider, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled", Method -> "Push", MinIntervalSize -> 0.5, ImageSize -> {300, 25}},
 ControlPlacement -> {Left, Right, Bottom}]
```

[image: GIF]

Comment: You can check for example [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87698/18476) to see how to add interconnected `InputField`s.

Comment: Thank you so much. One more followup question. How can you use `LocalizeVariables -> False` in `Manipulate` using two interval sliders?

Comment: @Wilson You mean avoiding the initial red coloring? Use the [`Initialization`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Initialization.html) option: `Initialization :> (vMax = 0; vMin = -1; xInt = {0, 5};)`

Comment: Not exactly, although that would also be nice to add. I am trying to keep the interval sliders at the same values when the user decides to input a new function. For example, if I keep the slider at {1,3} in the x interval slider above and the user decides to plot a new function, `Manipulate` would change the plot of the graph but keeps the sliders at {1,3}. I think this is done using `LocalizeVariables->False` but I may be incorrect. Thanks!

Comment: @Wilson `LocalizeVariables->False` makes `vMax`, `vMin`, and `xInt` global variables (meaning, e.g., `vMax` gets defined outside of `Manipulate` and has the same value as inside `Manipulate`). Maybe you are looking for [`SaveDefinitions->True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SaveDefinitions.html).

Comment: @Wilson The user should not need to reevaluate the `Manipulate` after inputting a new function. Either make the function definition something outside of `Manipulate` (e.g. `f[x_]:=Sin[10/x]`  and then `Plot[f[x], ...`), or make it part of the `Manipulate` (selecting a function or using an `InputField`).

Comment: Well, I thought that by defining `vMax`, `vMin` and `xInt` to be global variables, that would allow me to use these values to keep the sliders at their current position. However, when I use `LocalizeVariables->False`, I get what I want but with a few errors. Namely, a `PlotRange` error on the first evaluation, and that the sliders by default are placed on the interval {1.25,3.75}. Evaluations proceeding after the first are perfectly fine. Do you know a fix to this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43261/discussion-between-wilson-and-karsten-7).